# How to remove end of file names?

Tags: bash, rename, mv, filename

I want to rename a lot of files like `1_16_video1.mp4?1578683110081` & `54_127_video7.mp4?168302` to `1_16_video1.mp4` & `54_127_video7.mp4`.

How can I rename them?

Comment: `rename` allows the use of regex, but have you haven't said what part you want to rename, and what to.

Comment: @guiverc I want to remove the numbers after the `mp4` suffix. Look at the names precisely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using bash `for` loop and parameter expansion:

```
for i in *.mp4*; do 
  mv "$i" "${i%\?*}"
done
```

The parameter expansion is mentioned in the man page as

> ${parameter%word}  Remove  matching  suffix  pattern.

It removes everything after the last `?` included.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install krusader
sudo apt install krename
```

start krusader, highlight which files, or 'select all', 'file multirename' ,  click 'insert part of filename' button, swipe over the part and carefully check if the results are what you want before proceeding.